# What does the number in sysctl configuration file denote?

Tags: linux, sysctl

The sysctl utility allows a Linux admin to query and modify kernel parameters in runtime. For example, to change the swappiness of a linux system to 0 we can:

1. `echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`

Or we can use sysctl

2. `sysctl -w vm.swappiness=0`

To make the value persistent, [Archwiki suggests](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Swap#Swappiness) to write`vm.swappiness=0`  to `/etc/sysctl.d/99-swappiness.conf` file.

For persistent [silent boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Silent_boot#sysctl), Archwiki suggests to write `kernel.printk = 3 3 3 3` to `/etc/sysctl.d/20-quiet-printk.conf`

Similarly I have a `99-sysrq.conf` on my system which works without the number as well.

---

Archwiki has a [sysctl page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sysctl#Configuration) which mentions the importance of the number:

> Note: From version 207 and 21x, systemd only applies settings from
>   /etc/sysctl.d/*.conf and /usr/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf. If you had
>   customized /etc/sysctl.conf, you need to rename it as
>   /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf. If you had e.g. /etc/sysctl.d/foo, you
>   need to rename it to /etc/sysctl.d/foo.conf.

---

What does the number in `99-swappiness.conf` and `20-quiet-printk.conf` denote here?

Comment: Questions about the Linux operating system should be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ Please delete this and ask over there. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the order in which the files are read. By prefixing it with a two-digit number you can simply order in by the ascii-value of its characters. `20-quiet….conf` comes before `99-swapiness.conf`. (Try it with `ls` which sorts by default).

This follows the convention already used by SysV init system. Quoted from the **Sequencing directories** section of the very useful [`boot`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/boot.7.html) manpage:

> To define the starting or stopping order within the same run-level, the       name of a link contains an order-number.  Also, for clarity,  the  name       of a link usually ends with the name of the service to which it refers.       For example, the link `/etc/rc2.d/S80sendmail` starts the  sendmail service on runlevel 2.  This happens after `/etc/rc2.d/S12syslog` is run but before `/etc/rc2.d/S90xfs` is run.

Comment: Hi, this question is off-topic here, and can't be moved to unix.stackexchange.com. Can you please edit and copy your answer and post it on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/570770/what-does-the-number-in-sysctl-configuration-file-denote
?
So I can delete it.

Comment: @S.Goswami feel free to answer the question on unix.stackexchange.com yourself. Self-answering is allowed and encouraged